# Create .dll with Visual Studio

Tags: opencv, dynamic, dll, hyperlink

I want to create my own .dll file with visual studio.

The problem is, that I have included Open CV inside my program, because I'm using a method from Open CV.

My question now is, is it possible to create my own .dll file although I'm using a Open CV library? Is the Open CV lib, included inside my own .dll than, or how does it work?

Thank and best wishes,
Andi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this in two ways:

1. Statically link OpenCV into your DLL
2. Run-time Dynamically link OpenCV from your DLL

The first one requires you to build OpenCV as a static library (output is a large .lib file, no .dll).

In your own DLL, you specify you want to link with opencv.lib.

The second one requires you to build OpenCV as a dynamic library (output is a small .lib file, and a big .dll).

In your own DLL, you would have to add code to manually load the OpenCV library and find the addresses of the functions you need to call from OpenCV (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)